# Creating a PHP script that takes images for a other site

Tags: php, image

I am working on a script to show the sponsors of a other site. This needs to take these sponsors from that original website so when they add sponsors my script also ads these sponsors.

I got this to work locally by saving them in a folder and then use scandir to scan the names of the images and then display them using a for loop.

here is that code:

```
<?php
$dir = "path/to/images/";
$files = array_slice(scandir($dir), 2);
shuffle($files);

for($i=0; $i<=count($files)-1; $i++){
   echo "<img style='width:100px;' src='images/{$files[$i]}'/><br>";
}
?>
```

I need this to work but from a website or server and not just locally

Comment: So, what errors are you getting and are you checking for them? I don't know if this question should be closed as unclear, or why this isn't working.

Comment: #fred -ii- The script needs to take the pictures from the original website not from a folder that is saved localy. Doing this as the code above with a url instead of a path gives an error message saying that it cant open it. So im asking how else i could do this.

Comment: How often do you add sponsors? You can add a webservice, an API, RESTful service, etc. to present the path of the images to the other website. Then save the images list in a file or a database.

Comment: its for a client so they shouldnt have to do anything to make this work. just add images on site 1 and they should appear at site two. It has to be monkey proof.